# usb gets disabled after every 15 mins

Tags: usb, mouse, power

hi i have a pentium 4 pc with intel 845 glad motherborad running windows xp,the problem is that after every 10-15 minutes the mouse stops working because the usb loses its power supply and if remove and plug in again it starts working again.
i have tried this with diffrent mouses and all these mouse are working fine on other pc.
so please help me find out the solution to it. 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Before you drop the mouse, check this short list.

1. Have you checked **this** mouse on **another pc**?

   - Have you checked **another** mouse on **this** pc?
     I ask these questions because your long sentence left me a bit unclear.

Then,

1. Does your machine have multiple USB ports (most have),
   and, have you checked the mouse on different ports?

   - Have you checked other USB devices (like external drives of large flash drives)?
   - You could give a short try to this Microsoft KB article
     (it may not be necessarily related, but no harm checking),
     [**USB port may stop working after you remove or insert a USB device**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817900)

Comment: hi nik its happening to all the mouse and this is a motherborad or windows xp error ,and all these mouse work fine on other pc's 
and ya since you have mentioned i have 4 ports the problem is that also only two  usb work's at a time like if mouse and keyboard are plugged in and i insert my portable hard disk then mouse goes off

Comment: sounds to me like some kind of power-to-usb issue. Could be that the actual wiring isn't conncted properly from your USB ports to the motherboard, causing faulty USB-functionality

Comment: @manpreet, Is your external hdd externally powered or using USB power? You could check with an externally powered USB hub. I agree with `Pavsaund`s comment. And, do get a good hub (its for power not extensibility).

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked this?
Right click on the "My Computer" icon
Select properties
Select hardware
Select device manager
Open "Universal Serial Bus controllers" (near the bottom)
Right click on "USB Root Hub" & select properties
Select the Power Management tab
Make sure that the box for "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is not ticked.
Do this for each USB Root Hub on your PC

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem with several of our older Dell machines.Easiest solution was to buy inexpensive 4 or 5 port adapter cards and not worry with onboard ports.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something special about this mouse? It sounds like a connection problem (dry joint or similar), and unless it's a high-end mouse, it may not be worth your time debugging it if other mice are working and it can be replaced.

Comment: no salmon its happening to all the mouse and this is a motherborad or windows xp error .and all these mouse work fine on other pc's